# Google geolocation API not working after billing enabled

Tags: python, google-maps, google-geolocation

I get the following error message when searching for addresses in Google's geolocation API:

**"ApiClientException: Over your quota."**

I have enabled billing for the geolocation API, but it still only allows me to fetch 2500 addresses per day. I have tried to restart the programme, but this didn't work.

I have Python 3 and the code looks like the following:

```
from geolocation.main import GoogleMaps

google_maps = GoogleMaps(api_key='MY_KEY')

location = google_maps.search(location="some_address")
```

So, how come I keep getting the "Over your quota" error when I have enabled billing to the API?

Comment: have you checked your api request limit ?

Comment: Yes. On my Google dashboard, it says I have made zero requests. In Python, however, I keep getting the "Over your quota" message, because I already requested the 2.500 limit (which is true). What I don't understand is, why can't I go above 2.500 when I have enabled billing for my project and the geolocation API.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution.

Instead of using geolocation, I used geocoding. This works smoothly with the billing option.

```
import googlemaps

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='THE_GOOGLE_API_KEY')

geocode_result = gmaps.geocode("my_address")
```